# ClientException in io_client.dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http, dart-http

The code below works started giving trouble when the back-end server is switched from HTTP to HTTPS. The back-end application is written in .NET and runs on IIS 10.0

```
response = await http.post(
          Uri.encodeFull("https://_____________/api/account/login"),
          body: json.encode(body),
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
            // ignore: missing_return
          }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () {
        throw ('You seem to be offline');
      });
      if (response.statusCode == 500) {
         .......
```

See the screenshot below for exact exception. Interestingly, there's no exception message.

[image]

The code works well on other HTTPS back-end such as MS Azure hosted APIs. The API call works well in the Postman.

Can anyone help ?

EDIT : Found a related github [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37695)

Comment: what is the response status BTW?

Comment: also is this API working correctly in postman?

Comment: All okay in Postman. Can’t get to response status since it goes into the exception.

Comment: never encountered the same issue, but could be somehow related to signed certificates??

Comment: The issue seems to be in the dart SDK. Please see the 'edit' section in the question. There's an open github issue for this.

Comment: Could be the same, try posting this question on that GitHub issue too. also upvoting the question for better reach

Comment: also edit the question that the api call works fine in postman, will help other members to solve this

Comment: Good point. Done. Thanks Akshit for your efforts.